# read url entered in a browser's address bar using JAVA

Tags: url, classification

i want to write a java application that will classify url into malicious and benign.
ie when the user types a url in the address bar, my program should read that url , classify it and block it if it is malicious. 
how do i read the url from address bar of a browser once the user has entered it..

please help..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should implement this as an HTTP proxy, not a browser extension.  Then you can focus on your algorithm instead of the details of integrating Java with the various browsers.